# Find all words after specific string

Tags: grep, sed, awk

So, here's the thing.
I have a file contains like this:

```
LOG=123 HEY=BRO FOO=BAR LOG=124
```

I need the value of LOG= and an output like this:

```
123
124
```

I already tried using this command:

```
echo "$LOG" | egrep -o 'LOG=.*'
```

but it only outputs everything after the first word and not the values of all words with LOG=

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking only for the numeric values, you can use below command

```
grep -oE 'LOG=([0-9]+)' log | cut -d= -f2
```

If the value can be alphanumeric, use below command

```
grep -oE 'LOG=([A-Za-z0-9]+)' log | cut -d= -f2
```